# open & write a file in current directory of the c file

Tags: c

how to read & write to a file in current directory according to the .c file ?
for example my c file in c:\folder\source  (the c file may be placed in other folder)

```
fpin=fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
```

if don't specific the path, the program will open the textfile of the project path in borland c++

Comment: How would the compiled program know where your .C file was? What would it do if you ran it on another computer?

Comment: the program can detect where is the .c file, read & write the text file at the folder same as .c file. Suppose, the input text file and the output text file is always stay with the .c file

Comment: Bah.  I had a fair answer involving the `__FILE__` macro, mentioning that it was compiler dependent.  Then I remembered you specifically mentioned Borland C++.  It appears Borland does not give the full path in `__FILE__`.  I said this in my answer, but I deleted it, since it won't work: this is not a good idea.  Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to open with that technique, the file must be in the *executable's* directory, not in the source project directory.

Comment: This assumes the executable's directory is _also_ the _current working directory_, which is probably an incorrect assumption to make.